# Display a user-friendly message when JUnit tests fails

Tags: java, junit

I got the message like this.

```
com.controller.Test1 > test FAILED
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError at Test1.java:18
```

The dependencies for test compiling is

```
testCompile "junit:junit:4.11",
        'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19',
        'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.2.0',
        'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3',
        'org.flywaydb.flyway-test-extensions:flyway-dbunit-spring4-test:4.0'
```

And this is my test code.

```
package com.controller;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.instanceOf;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;


@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test1 {

   @Test
   public void test(){
      assertThat(Long.valueOf(1), instanceOf(Integer.class));
    }
}
```

I want the message like this.

Expected: an instance of java.lang.Integer
     but: <1L> is a java.lang.Long

Comment: how about using `assertTrue("messageIfFails", condition)`  ?

Comment: Or `org.junit.Assert.assertThat(String, Object, Matcher<? super Object>)` ?  The first param (string) is a reason which will be included in the message.  That being said, your test is failing with a `NoSuchMethodError`, not an assertion error, makes me think your classpath has problems.

Answer (score 2):

The `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` is not related to JUnit specifically. Instead, it indicates that the version of a class that was on your compiler's classpath is different from the version of the class that is on your runtime classpath.

The reason for the clash is that JUnit comes with its own `org.hamcrest.Matcher` class that is being used instead of the one imported in your code. Use `mockito-core` in your imports instead of `mockito-all` to exclude the matcher.